# Create Text area on the hover of the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I want to create a text area on the mouse hover in given link.

What I've tried is there in this  [fiddle code.](http://jsfiddle.net/viralshah/nmZb9/5/)

But I want to create text area dynamically when mouse over on the link.

This text area will set on the **right side** (when click on the link) and also declare some fields which supports **CSS for that text area** so, can able to modify the style of text area.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want a text area? Or a tool tip?

Comment: In Chrome you fiddle is working.

Comment: do you want to replace your link with a text area when you point mouse over?

Comment: the text area needs to work like a tooltip? i.e. disappears on mouseleave?

Comment: you need the textarea on hover or on click? the right side of the page or the right side of the link? (or the right side of the force? search inside your feelings, Viral)

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano, On hover the text area should be on the right side (given question fiddle its on left side).. Also I will be able to put CSS for that text area also

Comment: i edited fiddle and answer about 5 hours ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nmZb9/18/

**UPDATE:**I would do it like this if it is tooltip you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/nmZb9/24/

Answer (score 0):

On mouseover of the link call one ajax which gets the html of the textarea or create one hidden elment in html and do show/hide functionality using jquery  on mouseover event of jquery

for example link id is #link1 and one div element which holds textare id div1

jQuery('#link1 ').hover(function() {
      jQuery('#div1').show();
}, function() {
      jQuery('#div1').hide();
});

Comment: could you please show this by code in fiddle/ here direct on stack?

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div id="container" style="height:100px;">
</div>
<a href="foo.com" onmouseover="addTextarea('foo.com is a great site')" onmouseout="$('#container').empty();">Foo.com</a>
<a href="bar.com" onmouseover="addTextarea('bar.com is a terrible site')" onmouseout="$('#container').empty();">Bar.com</a>
```

JS:

```
function addTextarea(str) {
    $('#container').html(
    $('<textarea></textarea>')
      .val(str))
}​
```

Comment: why did down-vote? you hadn't explain it with fiddle and on my conditional fiddle it wasn't working that's why I commented as not working !! is it make sense to down-vote?

Comment: @ViralShah there are 7 answers on this question, neither of them answers your needs? It seemed for me that you want us to do your job. Sorry if wrong :)

Comment: Happy Now !? Finally you can find the right answer, if I want to do my Job from Stack then I can put live example on my fiddle !!

Comment: @ViralShah relax man :) It does not make me happy to down-vote, especially if it affected you so much.

Answer (score 0):

here my 2 cent, http://jsfiddle.net/BsTTr/4/

entirely vanilla javascript (no frameworks)

edit: added css rule to float textarea container to the right

Comment: yes, this one is the great can you put this textarea on right side corner with this same effect

Comment: i think that now you need only some css to style it.  if you need help on css you could look here [http://www.w3schools.com/css/](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you are looking for:

html:

```
<span>
    <textarea id="text1" style="display:none" onmouseout="showText(1,false)"></textarea>
    <a href="foo.com" id="link1" onmouseover="showText(1,true)">foo.com</a>
</span>
<span>
    <textarea id="text2" style="display:none" onmouseout="showText(2,false)"></textarea>
    <a href="bar.com" id="link2" onmouseover="showText(2,true)">bar.com</a>
</span>
```

js:

```
function showText(i, show) {

    var text, link;

    if (i == 1) {
        text = document.getElementById('text1');
        link = document.getElementById('link1');
    } else {
        text = document.getElementById('text2');
        link = document.getElementById('link2');
    }
    if (show) {
        text.style.display = 'inline';
        link.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        text.style.display = 'none';
        link.style.display = 'inline';
    }

}​
```

Here is the link to try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/dNuy6/3/

This is what I understand from you question. I replace the link with the text area on mouse over. If this is not what you are looking for, please give a more accurate explanation.

The problem with this approach is that the user never can click on the link!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve your goal this way - http://jsfiddle.net/nmZb9/27/. 
This one is without an obtrusive js (onmouseover attributes)

Comment: What way? Please post here, in this answer, the important parts of your answer, so that someone does not need to visit an external site to understand what your answer is.